# Selenium webdriver Chrome Method get

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I installed Chrome webdriver and when I execute the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome ()
driver.get ('https://www.google.com')
```

It starts with the blank page, it runs the line 2, opens the chrome driver, but it stays on the white screen .... it's as if there was no code on line 3 ... can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please delete blank spaces between Chrome,get and brackets . driver.get('https://www.google.com')

Answer (score 0):

Though you are trying to write this in python & the answer is in java but still I am posting this, check the logic & setup whether it can help you by any means.

`WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe" );
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(1000);`